# cross site scripting

Tags: php, javascript

Can I call a URL from a different host and write a variable to it without running into XSS security issues? This is what i am trying to do-

Send usernames + load a url in iframes from my site to a different site. I am doing this in javascript. I am actually able to do this but I am reading that browsers should be blocking it and its possibly a security concern?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using jQuery, please read:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-jsonp1/

Answer (score 0):

Edit: *-Nevermind, any in-browser editor can hack it still. I wouldn't know any option, beside htmlentities() the data after you recieved it.*

Answer (score 0):

If you control both domains you can just host a script on one domain to proxy the request to the other.  It'll add some latency to the picture, but it will work.